# Replace values of one DataFrame using the value of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as shown below and I have to correct values in Dataframe1 using values in Dataframe2. This may be very basic but I am just starting with pandas therefore unable to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated!

Dataframe 1 :

```
  Product_ID  count  weight       date
0      pid_1      2      10  1/01/2023
1      pid_1      3      20  1/02/2023
2      pid_2      4      30  1/01/2023
3      pid_2      2      40  1/02/2023
4      pid_3      3      50  1/01/2023 
5      pid_4      6      100 1/01/2023
```

Dataframe 2:

```
  Product_ID  count  weight
0      pid_1      2      10
1      pid_2      3      20
2      pid_3      4      30
```

Desired output:

```
  Product_ID  count  weight       date
0      pid_1      2      10  1/01/2023
1      pid_1      2      10  1/02/2023
2      pid_2      3      20  1/01/2023
3      pid_2      3      20  1/02/2023
4      pid_3      4      30  1/01/2023
5      pid_4      6      100 1/01/2023
```

Comment: What is the logic to align the two dataframes? Do you consider only Product_ID to be always correct?

Comment: Dataframe 2 contains the correct count and weight values for each product ID. The count and weight values need to be updated in Dataframe 1 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is unclear, it looks like you could just drop the count/weight columns from `df1` and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1[['Product_ID', 'date']].merge(df2, how='left')[df1.columns]
```

Output:

```
  Product_ID  count  weight       date
0      pid_1      2      10  1/01/2023
1      pid_1      2      10  1/02/2023
2      pid_2      3      20  1/01/2023
3      pid_2      3      20  1/02/2023
4      pid_3      4      30  1/01/2023
```

To handle non matching rows, add a [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = (df1[['Product_ID', 'date']].merge(df2, how='left')
       .combine_first(df1)[df1.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
  Product_ID  count  weight       date
0      pid_1    2.0    10.0  1/01/2023
1      pid_1    2.0    10.0  1/02/2023
2      pid_2    3.0    20.0  1/01/2023
3      pid_2    3.0    20.0  1/02/2023
4      pid_3    4.0    30.0  1/01/2023
5      pid_4    6.0   100.0  1/01/2023
```

*Note that for this to work, you shouldn't have duplicated Product_ID in `df2`.*

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77000940/edit) those details in the question directly and ensure correct formatting